# Calling sqlCommand in a loop increasing exec time every step

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I've got a loop that executes the stored procedure in a loop with over 40,000 iterations, like so:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("WriteDataToDB");
        command.Connection = _connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add("@SignalID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Arg_Signal.SignalID;
        command.Parameters.Add("@SignalStrength", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Arg_Signal.SignalSiggestion;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Arg_Signal.TimeWasHit;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Arg_Signal.ValueWasHit;

        if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
        }
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code is called from a loop where I intercept and time every 1000th iteration. The times I get are below:

[0]: "Started 0ms"
[1]: "1000 done 578.125ms"

[2]: "1000 done 921.875ms"

[3]: "1000 done 1328.125ms"

[4]: "1000 done 1734.375ms"

[5]: "1000 done 1140.625ms"

[6]: "1000 done 1250ms"

[7]: "1000 done 1703.125ms"

[8]: "1000 done 1718.75ms"

......

[31]: "1000 done 3234.375ms"

[32]: "1000 done 3390.625ms"

[33]: "1000 done 3453.125ms"

[34]: "1000 done 3609.375ms"

[35]: "1000 done 3765.625ms"

[36]: "1000 done 3796.875ms"

[37]: "1000 done 3968.75ms"

[38]: "1000 done 4093.75ms"

[39]: "1000 done 4203.125ms"

[40]: "1000 done 4546.875ms"

[41]: "1000 done 4406.25ms"

[42]: "Stopped with total 101093.75ms  1515.625ms"

Does anyone have an idea why these execution times are increasing? I need to run this code with over a million iterations - by the rate its going its going to take a minute to execute one iteration...

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any special logic in your stored proc or are you just inserting into a table.

If there is no special logic or you can do that logic in .NET then have a look at performing a [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). You can do this by utilising the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` class.

Comment: There actually is. The stored proc is first determening if the record exists and then inserts or updates it. I added an index that covers the columns on which its looking up, and got uniform execution time, with overall times increase of 20-fold. Thanks!

Comment: That would account for your results as your table size increases so does the time taken to perform a table scan. :)

Comment: @Michael, then maybe a judicious index is in order?

Comment: Just a tip on checking if a record exists, right now it sounds like you're using a 'look before you leap' approach:
IF exists (select from t where ...) 
    update t set ..
else 
    insert t() values()

Faster way to do that is the 'optimistic' approach:
update t set ..   -- assume it exists
if @@Rowcount = 0 -- record did not exist 
    insert t (..) values (..)

With the number of records you're pushing I'd also go with the SqlBulkCopy to a staging table with no index, and then cal an SP with a merge statement to put the records in the real destination table, truncate the staging table.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I know why you it goes slower each time (it would sound like you are not actually clearing the "1000" each time, but actually appending them or something) but if you are looking to dump data into a database you should be using something like [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a(VS.80).aspx), not a stored proc inside a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but you're adding more parameters on each iteration. Yes, they have the same names as before, but I don't know if the `SqlCommand` class is clever enough to handle that or not. Try adding the parameters once and then just setting their value in the loop, ie.

Outside of the loop:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@SignalID", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Inside the loop:

```
command.Parameters["@SignalID"].Value = Arg_Signal.SignalID;
```

If that doesn't help you'd have to profile the code and see where it's slow - it may not be the actual DB call.

As an aside, you could also try calling `command.Prepare()` when executing the same command many times - it wouldn't fix this particular problem, but may just make a slight performance difference for the better anyway.